# Prevent insert after first execution of my method

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am doing some changes in an existing project and I want to add a new `Column` in my `DataGridView`. I am doing the following:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
cb.HeaderText = "Process";
cb.Width = 100;
dgvVacationCalendar.Columns.Insert(2,cb );
```

The problem is that the method where I'm executing this piece of code is being called multiples times resulting in multiple inserts.

How can I prevent this insert to happen after the first time this method is being called?

Comment: Check if there's a column called "Process" before inserting?

Comment: You should check if the column exits or not before inserting it.

Comment: still no luck...this validation is not working if (!dgvVacationCalendar.Columns.Contains("Process")), everytime i enter in the method is still false.

Comment: That's because "Process" is the `HeaderText`, not the column's `Name` and the `Contains()` function only works with the `Name` property, not the `HeaderText`. See my answer for how to set the `Name` property. If you don't want to use the `Name` property, you'll have to check the  `HeaderText` in a loop or easier using LINQ. However, this will be very brittle as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way with your current code is to check the number of columns and only add the new column if that number was the original.

Let's say your grid has 5 columns, you can do this:

```
if(dgvVacationCalendar.Columns.Count == 5) {
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    cb.HeaderText = "Process";
    cb.Width = 100;
    dgvVacationCalendar.Columns.Insert(2, cb);
}
```

Alternatively, you can check if the grid has a column with the `HeaderText = "Process"` and only add it if the grid doesn't have it.

However, the problem with both approaches is that they are very brittle. If in the future your grid columns change, those two approaches may work incorrectly and you will waste sometime trying to find the bug. It is then better to give your column a unique name:

```
cb.Name = "ProcessColumn";
```

And then you can check if the grid has a column with that name:

```
if(!dgvVacationCalendar.Columns.Contains("ProcessColumn")) {
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    cb.HeaderText = "Process";
    cb.Width = 100;
    dgvVacationCalendar.Columns.Insert(2, cb);
}
```

This is a much more future-resilient approach. If try to add another column with the same name, you will get a clear error.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
if(!dataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>().Any(x=> x.HeaderText == "Process")) {
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    cb.HeaderText = "Process";
    cb.Width = 100;
    dgvVacationCalendar.Columns.Insert(2,cb );
}
```

Or you can use `ColumnAdded` event like this:

```
private void DataGridView1_ColumnAdded(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
{
    foreach(DataGridViewColumn item in dataGridView1.Columns)
    {
        if(e.Column.HeaderText == item.HeaderText)
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns.Remove(e.Column);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

im not sure if i have to open a new question here. But as an update to my previous question.Now it doesn't show my list in DataGridViewComboBoxColumn, what am i missing here?

```
this.DataGridView1.ColumnCount = Constants.Vacation_Calendar.Total_Calendar_Days + 2;
        this.DataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Resource";
        this.DataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 100;
        this.DataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Month";
        this.DataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = 60;



        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        List<Process> getAllProcesses = this.bl_process.getAll_Process();
        List<String> getApplication= new List<string>();


        foreach (Process process in getAllProcesses)
        {
            getApplication.Add(process.Application);
        }



        if (!DataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>().Any(x => x.Name == "ProcessColumn"))
        {
            cb.HeaderText = "Process";
            cb.Name = "ProcessColumn";
            cb.Width = 100;
            cb.DataSource = getApplication;
            cb.ReadOnly = false;
            DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(2, cb);
        }
```

plus despite the fact that i was not inserting a new columns anymore i was still getting an error that i handled like this :

```
in the designer
```

this.DataGridView1.DataError += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewDataErrorEventHandler(this.DataGridView1_DataError);

```
and in codebehind:

private void DataGridView1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
```